# Show installed packages by PPA

Tags: apt, ppa

Is it possible to list all packages installed by a PPA? I was cleaning up my PPA list recently, removing things I'm not using anymore, and there was one PPA where I was not sure if I even have the software installed.

Comment: Instead of cleaning up manually and searching for packages, `ppa-purge` would have done this for you.

Comment: `dpkg -l | awk '/^.i/ {print $2}' | xargs apt-cache policy | awk '/^[a-z0-9.\-]+:/ {pkg=$1}; /\*\*\*/ {OFS="\t"; ver=$2; getline; print pkg,ver,$2,$3}'| egrep -v "archive.ubuntu.com|/var/lib/dpkg/status" | awk '{printf "%-30s %-36s %-60s %-20s \n",$1,$2,$3, $4}'` works only if package source still is present. but ppa-purge is still easier to use.